# How do I design my Recycler View to be similar to this design from Chanel App?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I need to design my Recycler View as follows and I need ideas to go around with it.

[image]

I have some ideas regarding it. I know I would probably need to override a LayoutManager, but I have no idea how to approach that. So I just wanted to ask where or how can I go around with designing something like this.
The top item is the one which gets expanded or highlighted on scroll with some sort of parallax animation.

Comment: Check this link - https://medium.com/mindorks/hack-that-recyclerview-f6b8238e68ec , this explain same requirement

Answer (score 0):

see this project https://github.com/andriipanasiuk/ExpandableRecyclerView

This project same as your requirement.

Comment: It is similar but not the same. It is more of a Expandable List View sort of thing in the project you linked where on link the child view gets expanded. In the GIF I have linked there is no such child view. The image size I think is being altered.